# force close windows and last empty buffer

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, neovim

When I open multi windows like the below:

```
vim foo.txt bar.txt
```

Then, if close `foo.txt` by `:bw`
then, close `bar.txt` by `:bw`

- vim is still open! , it should close by `:q`
- I don't want vim steel opened if the last buffer that already killed
- or do I want to make one keybinding to kill empty/non-empty windows too
  I want to make a map key to quit windows one by one like that:

```
function! Quitwindows()
    if bufexists(0) && bufname(0) == ''
      exe ':qall<cr>' 
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <Space>q :call Quitwindows()
```

Comment: “Closing buffers” isn’t a traditional vim thing. Not that you’re doing anything wrong, just that most people tend to ignore any kind of buffer management. They all go away when you exit. I use windows or tabs to look at multiple files (or multiple parts of a file) simultaneously, and close those when done, but in general “not looking at a buffer” is the closest I come to “closing” one unless I need to open the file in a different vim instance (rare)

Comment: I second the previous comment. BTW, for added perspective, I've been a heavy and pretty advanced user of Vim for many years and I have _never_ ... like, for real, not one single time ... used `:bw`. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use this function

```
function! Quitwindows()
    let s:total_nr_buffers = len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'))
    if  s:total_nr_buffers == 1
      exit 
    else
      bw
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <Space>q  :call Quitwindows()<cr>
```

Comment: A good answer would have some explanatory text to go with the code and wouldn't have sloppy code with unreachable statements and unnecessary/unhelpful comments. FYI.

Comment: it's right , bur sometime any one can edit answer or question for better syntax and correct langue, thx @B_Layer